# Dart false runs fine for the first time but if I run the code again and start with a true it becomes an infinity loop even if I enter a false

Tags: dart

---

Greetings! when I run this code and enter a false(Allan) the first time the code executes well but if I run it a again and enter a true(eg John,Eric etc) the code, it becomes an infinity loop even if I enter a false in the middle of the program stops

```dart
void main() {
  print('Please enter the user name:');
  var userName = stdin.readLineSync()!;

  while (userName != 'Allan') {
    print('Sorry that is not the correct user name. Please try Again');
    var userName = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  }
  print('Hey $userName welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining two different variables called `userName` where the first are defined inside the `main()` method while the other are inside the scope of the `while()` loop.

When accessing a variable, Dart will search for it from the scope where you are and then widen the search to outer scopes if it does not find the variable. But the expression used by `while` when determining of the loop should continue, cannot access the scope defined inside the loop. So it sees the first `userName` variable defined in `main()`.

So the problem is that when you use `var`, you are telling Dart that it should define a new variable instead of using an existing one.

So instead of:

```dart
    print('Sorry that is not the correct user name. Please try Again');
    var userName = stdin.readLineSync()!;
```

You should just do the following to refer to the existing variable called `userName`:

```dart
    print('Sorry that is not the correct user name. Please try Again');
    userName = stdin.readLineSync()!;
```